# which jars are needed for using AspectJ of Spring framework?

Tags: spring, netbeans, jakarta-ee, aspectj

```
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;

@Aspect
public class AroundExample {

  @Around("com.xyz.myapp.SystemArchitecture.businessService()")
  public Object doBasicProfiling(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    // start stopwatch
    Object retVal = pjp.proceed();
    // stop stopwatch
    return retVal;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need current version of aspectj jars i.e. `aspectjrt-1.6.6.jar` and `aspectjweaver-1.7.2.jar` with other jars shown in the below image to work with AspectJ of Spring framework.

[image: required to use apsectJ]

Answer (score 2):

The link provided in the accepted answer didn't work for me. So I had to get the jar from somewhere else. This is the [LINK](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/org/aspectj/aspectjrt/1.6.6/aspectjrt-1.6.6.jar)

The file is aspectjrt-1.6.6.jar

Comment: link is broken, please fix it if possible!

Answer (score 1):

this is [link](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect) to get jars

Comment: link is broken, please fix it if possible!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to find jars
http://findjar.com

Answer (score 0):

`aspectj-N.N.NN.jar`, where N is the version number.  See the [AspectJ download site](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/downloads.php).

Comment: Not quite correct, it is `aspectjrt-N.N.NN.jar`, i.e. the runtime, not any of the other JARs. This applies to CTW (compile-time weaving). For LTW (load-time weaving) you need `aspectjweaver-N.N.NN.jar`, but no additional runtime JAR because the weaving agent also contains the runtime.