# Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/annotation/Aspect

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I recently started working on `AspectJ` and wrote a simple Aspect for Logging.

I have defined below dependencies into my pom file:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

**And Following artifacts are present in ear/lib folder:**

- aspectjrt-1.7.1.jar
- aspectjweaver-1.7.1.jar
- spring-aspects-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar

I am getting below exception on service startup.:

```
05:59:18,325 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-15) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'calNamingBean' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/helixservicebeans.xml]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/annotation/Aspect
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:452) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
                    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:740) [spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
                    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:449) [spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
                    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385) [spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
                    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284) [spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
                    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111) [spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
                    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:89) [jboss-as-web-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
                    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
                    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
            Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/annotation/Aspect
                    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AbstractAspectJAdvisorFactory.hasAspectAnnotation(AbstractAspectJAdvisorFactory.java:119) [spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
                    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AbstractAspectJAdvisorFactory.isAspect(AbstractAspectJAdvisorFactory.java:115) [spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
                    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.isInfrastructureClass(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:100) [spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
                    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:278) [spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:880) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
```

**Edit 1** - I am using `JBOSS 7.1` and I think there are some issues with `AspejctJ` and `JBOSS`.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33164216/load-time-weaving-with-aspectj-in-jboss-as-7-1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25861105/spring-aop-around-class-class-not-found-exception ?

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263311/which-jars-are-needed-for-using-aspectj-of-spring-framework

Comment: I have gone through both the questions and their answers. No luck. In Local, I can run using the same configuration but it fails when I am deploying it to JBoss server.

Comment: Bad advise: try to package jars of aspectJ in deployment unit like in `WEB-INF/lib/` if using `war`. Sometimes the execution environment do not provide class files of run-time dependencies as services. If it runs than you know the problem and fix it using proper way.

Also Check that if any class from aspecJ package needs to be declared as bean.

I am also facing similar problem with hibernate. I forced packaged jar and it ran.

Comment: What is your application? Did you use a quickstart or do you have a simple example piece of code?

Comment: your war in not properly built. Check your buildpath and add all required dependencies in lib folder inside WEB-INF and add lib folder(Add library --> web app libraries in eclipse ) in you build path.

Answer (score 20):

A **NoClassDefFoundError** like this in a maven project is usually from a library conflict.  There is insufficient information in the question, you only provide a snippet of your pom and don't show the version of spring aspects you are using.  You need to run **mvn dependency:tree** and verify you are using consistent version numbers of all of the aspectj depenendecies.

**Edit:**  There is definitely some kind of library conflict because you mention spring-aspects 3.2.1.RELEASE in the question, but the stack trace contains a lot of references to spring 3.1.1.RELEASE libraries.

Comment: There are no conflicts. I have verified it.

Comment: You either have a typo in your question or you have conflicting versions of libraries.  You should not have any 3.1.1.RELEASE versions of libraries (like in your stack trace) with 3.2.1.RELEASE version of spring aspects.

Answer (score 11):

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/annotation/Aspect

It seems jar containing class `org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect` is not loaded from `classpath` at runtime, can you try removing below dependency:

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

and add below in your classpath:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This is unnecessary, spring-aspects depends on spring-aop.  Maven pulls this in transitively without your edits.  Also, Aspect is not missing.  He's not getting a NoClassFoundException, which would means its missing,  He's getting a NoClassDefFoundError which just means the class wasn't loaded.

Answer (score 2):

**Answer to your Question**

1. If you are using [Spring 3.2.1.RELEASE](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22spring-framework-bom%22%20AND%20v%3A%223.2.1.RELEASE%22), please change your group id as net.anthavio.maven, I find only **aspectjweaver.1.7.4.jar** file is presented as a dependency. Please change your dependency for aspectjweaver as 1.7.4 version.
2. It is always recommended to use the Bill of Materials when you are using Spring 3.X and above.
3. I have given an example POM, you can validate accordingly to match with your existing POM.

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.yourcompany.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>springBOM</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.10.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
     </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
   </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>springBOM</finalName>
        <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
   </build>
</project>
```

4. It is recommended to choose Spring-3.2.10.RELEASE version as a standard version at is released on latest than your version mentioned in your question. It applies to this **specific context** only. Else I would recommend to upgrade your JAR files to Spring 4.X version.

Answer (score 2):

In order to check that your war was wrapped with the suitable jar (aspectrj - that really contain this class -org.aspect.lang.annotation.Aspect).

Try (within eclipse) to add this dependency manually.

right click on the project -> Deployment Assembly -> add -> Archives from file system -> pick the aspectjrt-1.7.1.jar (you can find it in your local .m2 repo).
apply
run the new war -> now the war should include this dependency. If the error message is gone -> that indicates that something went wrong with war packaging goal.